# It there an example of sum and product of continuous functions is not continuous?

Tags: general-topology

> The sum and product of two continuous functions is continuous

I can prove this easily when the space is metrizable, but I don't get it when the space is non-metrizable. Is there a counterexample of this? or it is true for all topological spaces those have a binary operation?

edit: It it true even if the space has a non-contionuous binary operation?

Comment: The proof is basically the same : it relies on the fact that $+:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\times :\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.

Comment: I don't get it why the summation and product are continuous even though the space is arbitrary.

Comment: The space is not arbitrary at all, it's $\mathbb{R}$ (of course you can replace it with a topological ring).

Comment: my question is it is true for all topological spaces those have a binary operation.

Comment: Almost. It's true for all topological spaces that have a *continuous* binary operation. Then use the same proof as with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Though you've got a good answer, you might consider making your question precise for the benefit of future readers. The comments indicate you're implicitly asking about $X$-valued maps on $X$, while the wording strongly suggests you mean _real-valued functions_.

Answer (score 12):

If $X$ is any space and $f,g: X \to \mathbb R$ are any two continuous functions, then $(f,g): X \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is continuous by definition (or construction) of the product, and $+: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function. Then $f+g = {+} \circ (f,g)$, and a composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Similarly for $\times$, of course.

Edit: or replace $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb C,\mathbb Q$, or any topological ring -- that is, a ring so that $+,-,\times$ are continuous.

Comment: how about over an arbitrary semigroup with topology?

Comment: @Jay: As Captain Lama already said above, the binary operation under consideration has to be continuous. In fact, if you have any topological space $X$ with a noncontinuous binary operation $*: X \times X \to X$ then you can find two continuous functions into $X$ whose $*$ is not continuous; namely, just take the two projections $X \times X \to X$.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer that I wanted.